# Unknown adaptor for 2009 Mazda 2 headlight

Tags: mazda, headlight, bulbs

I have a 2009 Mazda 2 Sport. Recently passengers side headlight bulb has blown. I went to Halfords and bought the correct bulb, a "477SB H7" 12V, 55W Super Brilliance.

Image of base:
[image]

I then went to fit the new bulb and noticed the old bulb was significantly larger. It is stamped with "H4 12V60/55W (E8) 3G6".

Image:
[image]

I then looked at the drivers side bulb and saw that it had the smaller bulb, like the new one I just bought. However it seemed to have some kind of adaptor:
[image]

What is this adaptor that I am missing from my passengers side?

Both bulbs side by side:
[image: Both side by side]

Comment: What does the harness connector look like?

Comment: @Ben it's a 3 prong, exactly like the reverse of (female for) the old bulb.

Comment: was the harness repaired? it sounds like someone did a repair and put the wrong end on

Comment: @Ben I don't think so. And the harness is the same on the other side.

Comment: [SO YOUR LOOKING FOR THIS?](http://www.nextdayauto.com/2009-mazda-3-headlight-bulb-retainer-dorman-w0133-2058176.html)

Comment: Do you have one bulb per side or 2? 3 prong bulbs are high and low beam, 2 prong is either high or low beam in a 4 lamp system. According to my (limited) reasearch the correct bulb is an H4. H7 is not listed for this year, make, model. Has the car been in an accident and perhaps the wrong headlamp assembly been installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third picture shows a black plastic adapter that you identify as missing from the one side.
And I assume your able to use the lamp and adapter from the side it was install in on the other side.
If so then you should find that the part missing Mazda 3 headlight bulb retainer can be found as new old stock Dorman part number WX-6255671.

[image: adapter]

The issue you may face is I have not successfully found that part number in the current 2016 Dorman catalogs so it may be discontinued.
In which case your ability to obtain one would be NOS on a part dealer shelf or a junk yard.

[Maybe in stock here at this time](http://www.nextdayauto.com/2009-mazda-3-headlight-bulb-retainer-dorman-w0133-2058176.html)